# Xamarin.ios doesn't build unless bin/obj folders are removed

Tags: c#, xamarin, compiler-errors, xamarin.ios, building

Hi,

I have a problem with the build on Xamarin.iOS part. I don't know exaclty what is the problem.
My solution doesn't build completly unless bin/obj folders are removed.

Context:

If I start VS2017 or 2019 I can build the solution.
If I made some changes, minor changes and then I rebuild the solution it will not work.

The first build is extremly slow (5min for a new project).

I got an error on Vs2017 and on 2019 it's a infinit building. 
It can only work if I remove obj and bin folders then clean and rebuild.
It's really annoying.

I have made a Microsoft support ticket to understant what is the problem.

It's only my computer, because if someone else try to compile on the Mac it's working.

I have made a Microsoft support ticket to understand what is the problem (I'm waiting).

Make a post here => https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/158080/second-time-building-extremely-long-and-fail-on-xamarin-ios#latest

On the MAC => I have tried different version of Mono SDK 5.18.1.3 but there is an mistake with this with Vs2019. I go back on 5.18.1.15. 
Now I'm on 5.18.1.28 for Mono Framework MDK.

I was on Xamarin.iOS 12.4.0.64 (for VS2017) move to 12.8.0.2 and 12.10.0.153 for VS 2019. I go back on 12.4.0.64 to work again with VS2017.

We can see on the Warning (In the log file)  =>

The client build1736klein has been disconnected while waiting a post response to topic xvs/Build/4.12.3.83/copy-item/XamarinHelloWorld.iOS/c913e05002fXamarinHelloWorld.iOS.exe

The underlying MQTT connection has been disconnected unexpectedely. Reason: RemoteDisconnected, Message: (IDTâche:88)

The AggregateException: One or more errors have occurred.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(795,3): error : ClientDisconnectedException: The client build1736klein has been disconnected while waiting a post response to topic xvs/Build/4.12.3.83/copy-item/XamarinHelloWorld.iOS/c913e05002fXamarinHelloWorld.iOS.exe
Execution of the "MTouch" task completed -- ÉCHEC. (IDTâche:88)

I can build only if I remove Obj and Bin folder and restart Visual Studio 2017. I don't know why there is a problem.

Visual Studio 2017 Pro is up to date. 
Mojave is up to date. 
On the Mac I work with Visual Studio 2019 Community

Someone have an idea what can I change ?
Thank you.

Comment: that happens to any project you make in your computer?

Comment: Yes, only with the iOS project (Forms or Native).

Comment: then it seems the problem might be on your Mac, do you have the latest Xcode Installed?

Comment: I'm not sur. If I build on a different MAC I have the same error. XCode is up to date. 10.2.1 (10E1001).

Comment: what? even with diferent mac? i would probably wait for microsoft response or post something on https://forums.xamarin.com , that's a first for me

Answer (score 0):

Error =>

> warning : The client build21656klein has been disconnected while
>   waiting a post response to topic
>   xvs/Build/4.12.3.83/copy-item/XamarinHelloWorld.iOS/c913e05002fXamarinHelloWorld.iOS.exe
>   1>  The underlying MQTT connection has been disconnected
>   unexpectedely. Reason: RemoteDisconnected, Message:  (IDTâche:90) 1> 
>   The underlying MQTT connection has been disconnected unexpectedely.
>   Reason: Error, Message: The client  has been disconnected while trying
>   to perform the unsubscribe to topics: xma/last-will (IDTâche:90) 1> 
>   The underlying MQTT connection has been disconnected unexpectedely.
>   Reason: Error, Message: The client  has been disconnected while trying
>   to perform the unsubscribe to topics: xma/last-will (IDTâche:90)
>   1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(795,3):
>   warning : The underlying client has been disconnected by the remote
>   host

And =>

> System.Net.Mqtt.MqttException: The keep alive tolerance of 00:00:45
>   seconds has been exceeded and no packet has been received from client
>   build21656klein. The connection will be closed. --->
>   System.TimeoutException: The operation has timed out.

[MQTT example](http://www.steves-internet-guide.com/mqtt-keep-alive-by-example/)

It was a really stupid problem. The network cable that was defective, but still working.